# jPod PDDocument.save() with ContentResolver in Android

Tags: android, pdf, outputstream, android-contentresolver

I'm using jPod for manipulating an existing PDF and store it again. But both, PDDocument creation and PDDocument.save() is getting me into some problems, as I want to use an Intent for getting an URI to load and store the PDF-File.

My PDDocument creation works as follows (the method is called out of onActivityResult):

```
protected void renderPDFInit(Uri uri) {
    try{
        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        InputStream stream = cr.openInputStream(uri);
        File file = File.createTempFile("pd", null);
        file.deleteOnExit();
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        IOUtils.copy(stream, out);
        FileLocator locator = new FileLocator(file);
        pdDocument = PDDocument.createFromLocator(locator);
        stream.close();
    }catch(IOException | COSLoadException e){
        Log.e(e.toString(), e.getMessage());
    }
```

Is there any better way to do that?

And for the PDDocument.save() I was thinking about something like:

```
private void savePdf(Uri uri){
    try {
        ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(uri, "w");
        if (pfd != null) {
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(pfd.getFileDescriptor());
            pdDocument.save(new FileLocator(something));
            pfd.close();
            fileOutputStream.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException | DocumentException e) {
        Log.e(e.toString(), e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

But I have no idea, how to instantiate the new FileLocator() as it needs an Object of Type File.

Comment: If FileLocator and the other "...Locator" classes are unusable for you, you need to implement your own ILocator, that can do what you want. PDDocument.save() will need random access, however, don't know if that can be done with what you have in mind. If working in memory is an option, you could also use a ByteArrayLocator for the PDF and copy the bytes.

Comment: That said, you might run into many more problems. jPod is written for J2SE and will expect a corresponding runtime.